# TinyMCE: Get orignial textarea reference within initialization

Tags: tinymce

## Problem

Width of the `<textarea>` is defined by CSS class, for ex.: `wMax` or `wDefault`. In first case it is 100%, in the second, lets say 200px. By default TinyMCE converts everything to fixed width in pixels. Ofcourse I can set `width:100%` inside `tinyMCE.init()`, but that will not cover textarea's with wDefault / fixed with.

## What I need

I need TinyMCE width to behave the same as original, % or px depending on it's CSS class.

If I could find a reference to the original textarea element within `tinyMCE.init()` procedure, then I could read CSS class from it, and set `width: (textarea.hasClass('wMax') ? '100%' : null)` or something like that

I am aware of the [getElement()](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getElement) function, which gets me exactly that textarea. But where do I run it from? tinyMCE.activeEditor is **null** within `init()`.

I'm currently still using TinyMCE 3, but it would be nice if you could answer this also for 4.x version, if there is any difference ofcourse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Sharing.

Answering my own question in the title: It's not possible to refer to the textarea within init() procedure directly, because it does not run for each tinyMCE instance. It runs only once. **But**: TinyMCE has a customizable setup function, which does run for every instance and has all required references to solve the mentioned problem.

With the following code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // ... your settings here ...
    setup: function(ed){
        if(ed.getElement().hasClass('wMax')){
            ed.settings.width = '100%';
        }
    }
});
```

Any textarea with CSS class 'wMax' (replace with your own) will be replaced by TinyMCE instance having 100% width. All others will have a fixed width, equal to the width of the textarea at the moment of initialization. You can expand this approach with any width, like wHalf width:50% etc.

Note: `.hasClass()` function is a part of Mootools JS library. Replace with another if you use a different library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will lead you  into the right direction. I use this code to adjust the iframe height to fit the entered content. You could tweak it a bit to adjust its height and width to your needs (you will need to get the textarea by `$('#' + ed.id)` onInit.
Here is the function. Basically it changes the style attributes explicitly of the editor iframe

```
    resizeIframe: function(frameid) {
        var frameid = frameid ? frameid : this.editor.id+'_ifr';
        var currentfr=document.getElementById(frameid);

        if (currentfr && !window.opera){
            currentfr.style.display="block";
            if (currentfr.contentDocument && currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight) { //ns6 syntax
                currentfr.height = currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 26;
            }
            else if (currentfr.Document && currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight) { //ie5+ syntax
                    currentfr.height = currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight;
            }
            styles = currentfr.getAttribute('style').split(';');
            for (var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
                if ( styles[i].search('height:') ==1 ){
                    styles.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }
            };
            currentfr.setAttribute('style', styles.join(';'));
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thariama, thanks for sharing your code. However I don't think I will be implementing this workaround because of it's size, browser dependency and approach. Speaking of workarounds, a far more stable workaround would be to wrap the editor inside a DIV and apply CSS to it.

Comment: you cannot wrap the tinymce editor into another element, because tinycme uses an own iframe (with own css)

Comment: I am wrapping it all the time, in div's, table cells etc. Just set tinyMCE width:100% and it will fit in any block level element.

Comment: which elemnt do you wrap? do you wrap it before initalization?

Comment: Yes I meant just simple wrapping textarea before initialization. `<div class="wrapper"><textarea></textarea></div>`. By doing this you can set TinyMCE width to 100% and set wrapper to any width by CSS. Dynamic or fixed. But again this is an unnecessary workaround. With the real "solution" I found, you don't need extra CSS rules, extra HTML, any JavaScript events or other browser dependent JS.

Comment: ok, this will work :) but keep in mind tinymce doesn't like to get moved around the DOM after it is initialized